# Object inverter in lodash without losing keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to `_.invert` an object with lodash, collecting the old keys into an array, rather than losing them.

Here's how I managed to do it:

```js
let tokens = {
    y: 'years',
    Y: 'years',
    M: 'months',
    mo: 'months',
    Mo: 'months',
    w: 'weeks',
    W: 'weeks',
    d: 'days',
    D: 'days',
    h: 'hours',
    H: 'hours',
    m: 'minutes',
    mi: 'minutes',
    Mi: 'minutes',
    s: 'seconds',
    S: 'ms'
  },
  print = JSON.stringify(inverter(tokens), null, 2);

document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = print;

function inverter(obj) {
  let out = {};
  _.forOwn(obj, (o, k) => {
    out[o] = _.concat(out[o] || [], [k]);
  });
  return out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Most of the time I feel my usage of the lib has the elegance of a swimming hammer, so my question would be: is there's a simpler, more elegant *"lodashy"* way than my current `inverter()` function?

Comment: Maybe do something using `_.groupBy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`_.invertBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#invertBy). According to the docs:

> The corresponding inverted value of each inverted key is an array of
>   keys responsible for generating the inverted value.

```js
const tokens = {"y":"years","Y":"years","M":"months","mo":"months","Mo":"months","w":"weeks","W":"weeks","d":"days","D":"days","h":"hours","H":"hours","m":"minutes","mi":"minutes","Mi":"minutes","s":"seconds","S":"ms"};
  
const result = _.invertBy(tokens);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: Lovely. I knew there was and I'm happy I asked. I'll accept in 8 minutes. No idea why, but it won't let me. Cheers!

Comment: So please what is the opposite of the function now, i.e something like spreadBy

Answer (score 0):

With Lodash 4.1.0 or greater you should be able to just do:

```
_.invertBy({
  y: 'years',
  Y: 'years',
  M: 'months',
  mo: 'months',
  Mo: 'months',
  w: 'weeks',
  W: 'weeks',
  d: 'days',
  D: 'days',
  h: 'hours',
  H: 'hours',
  m: 'minutes',
  mi: 'minutes',
  Mi: 'minutes',
  s: 'seconds',
  S: 'ms'
});
```